# Colisión de objeto de un juego en C

Tags: c

Necesito ayuda con un juego que estoy haciendo es parecido al Snake.
Mi problema es que cuando quiero hacer que el personaje se coma las palabras, estas no se cuentan hasta llegar a la esquina del personaje.

El problema principal es al comparar el if que marca la colision en la comida, el cual es este.

```
  void Food()
  { 

 if(head.x==food.x&&head.y==food.y||head.x+1==food.x+1&&head.y+1==food.y+1||
 head.x+2==food.x+2&&head.y+2==food.y+2)
   {
    length++;
    time_t a;
    a=time(0);
    srand(a);
    food.x=rand()%70;
    if(food.x<=10)
    food.x+=11;
    food.y=rand()%30;
    if(food.y<=10)

        food.y+=11;
}
else if(food.x==0)
    food.x=rand()%70;
    if(food.x<=10)
        food.x+=11;
    food.y=rand()%30;
    if(food.y<=10)
        food.y+=11;
 }
 }
```

`

Answer (score 0):

```
if(head.x==food.x&&head.y==food.y||head.x+1==food.x+1&&head.y+1==food.y+1||
head.x+2==food.x+2&&head.y+2==food.y+2)
```

Aquí no usas ni un solo paréntesis... ¿Estás seguro que la condición final es la que esperas?

Yo esperaría encontrarme más bien algo así:

```
if( (head.x==food.x && head.y==food.y)
 || (head.x+1==food.x+1 && head.y+1==food.y+1)
 || (head.x+2==food.x+2 && head.y+2==food.y+2))
```

Por cierto nota que aquí:

```
else if(food.x==0)
  food.x=rand()%70;
  if(food.x<=10)
    food.x+=11;
  food.y=rand()%30;
  if(food.y<=10)
    food.y+=11;
```

No tienes paréntesis... luego el código final es este (bien tabulado):

```
else if(food.x==0)
  food.x=rand()%70;

if(food.x<=10)
  food.x+=11;

food.y=rand()%30;
if(food.y<=10)
  food.y+=11;
```

Que sea el código que esperas o no solo lo sabes tú... pero mucho ojo con las tabulaciones del código y con el uso de las llaves.